# Optimizing sending a dataframe to hdf?

Tags: pandas, hdf

What is the difference between an h5 and hdf file? Should I use one over the other? I tried doing a timeit with the following two codes and it took about 3 minutes and 29 seconds per loop and with a 240mb file. I had an error eventually on the second code but the file size was above 300mb on disk.

```
hdf = pd.HDFStore('combined.h5')
hdf.put('table', df, format='table', complib='blosc', complevel=5, data_columns=True)
hdf.close()


df.to_hdf('combined.hdf', 'table', format='table', mode='w', complib='blosc', complevel=5)
```

Also, I had an error message which said:

```
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types
```

This is due to string columns which are objects because of blank values. If I do .astype(str), all of the blanks are replaced with nan (a string which even appears in output files). Do I worry about the error message and fill in the blanks and replace them again with np.nan later, or just ignore it?

Here is the df.info() to show that there are some columns with nulls. I can't remove these rows but I could temporarily fill them with something if required.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1387276 entries, 0 to 657406
Data columns (total 12 columns):
date                          1387276 non-null datetime64[ns]
start_time                    1387276 non-null datetime64[ns]
end_time                      313190 non-null datetime64[ns]
cola                          1387276 non-null object
colb                          1387276 non-null object
colc                          1387276 non-null object
cold                          476816 non-null object
cole                          1228781 non-null object
colx                          1185679 non-null object
coly                          313190 non-null object
colz                          1387276 non-null int64
colzz                         1387276 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](3), int64(2), object(7)
memory usage: 137.6+ MB
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no difference. `to_hdf` is just a higher level way of writing to hdf files. Someone probably knows more though.

Comment: Yeah, so far it seems fine to use to_hdf and ignore that performance warning... when I read the data back it looks like my dtypes are saved and it takes like 2 seconds to read the file which was originally a huge Excel workbook (read_excel seems to take forever and then I need to parse dates and stuff).

Comment: Yeah stay as far away from excel as you possibly can :)